# self.close() not working with a keycode event

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm trying to close the browser window with the ESC key, but dont know why the self.close dos not work.

this is what i'm doing (i try use `document` in place of `body` but nothing change ):

```
    $('body').keydown(function(e) {
          if(e.keyCode == 27){
                alert(e.keyCode); // alert work fine ( 27 ) 
                self.close();
          }
    });
```

what i'm missing ?

edit:

doing this work fine:

```
    $("#closeWindow").click(function(){
        self.close();
    });
```

thanks.

Comment: JavaScript can only close windows that JavaScript has opened.

Comment: why if i put in a click, the self close work ?

Comment: What is the `self` refer to? Caution on the scope of that variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your alert is working, I assume the self.close() is failing for security reasons.

This code is a hack to get around this security measure:

```
window.open('', '_self', '');
window.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Windows may only be closed via javascript if they were opened via javascript. If the window you are working with was not opened through code, you aren't going to be able to close it via code. See the section *Description* here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.close There are some old hacks to address this kicking around on the internet, but most are obsolete in more recent versions of browsers.

Also, you'll want to add the `keydown` event to `document` rather than the body element, and when you use `self.close()`, you're probably better off using `window.close()` to avoid confusion with scope - you want the window to close, so there's no harm in being explicit.

Answer (score 0):

Try `$(document)` instead. There is no 'body' object for you to attach to.